# rpy2 module is invisible from python 2.7 on Mac 10.6.8

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, rpy2, rpython

I am a bit of a noob on Mac and my python installation is refusing to acknowledge the existence of the rpy2 module on my mac. It looks like it only sees it as a Python 2.6 module. How do I make it visible in 2.7 ? Do I need to downgrade my python ? If so, how ? On the RPy2 web page (http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2_download.html) Python 2.6 is recommended. Thanks!

```
mayumi@MAYUMI-iMac~:/ python --version
Python 2.7.6
mayumi@MAYUMI-iMac~:/ pip install rpy2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): rpy2 in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rpy2-2.3.8-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg
Cleaning up...
mayumi@MAYUMI-iMac~:/ python
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rpy2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named rpy2
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found it is difficult to successfully install `rpy2` in OSX machines. Sometime it works, sometimes it doesn't, which is very annoying. I eventually settled with `Anaconda` `Python` distribution from https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/ to save all the troubles. Installing `rpy2` never fails since the switch.

The default installation of `Anaconda` does not included `rpy2`, so you want to run the installation command, from `Anaconda` folder, `bin` subfolder

conda install rpy2

Depends on the version, you may get a bunch of warnings. Just ignore them.

Then `rpy2` just works! Of course, only under the `Anaconda python`, not the other `python` version you may have installed on your machine.

[image]

You can run a few test to make sure `rpy2` works, following this example: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/ipython/ipython/3607712653c66d63e0d7f13f073bde8c0f209ba8/docs/examples/notebooks/rmagic_extension.ipynb

`bash` commands, run in the folder `/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/anaconda/bin/`:

```
user-Mac-Pro:bin user$ conda install rpy2
```

and it says:

```
Conda package not available for rpy2, attempting to install via pip
Downloading/unpacking rpy2
 Downloading rpy2-2.3.8.tar.gz (185kB): 185kB downloaded
 Running setup.py egg_info for package rpy2
```

If you don't have `R` installed it will complain with a few warnings and fetch `R` for you. Then there may be some other depreciation warnings dependents on what you have installed.

(I am not associated with Continuum in any way)

Comment: Thanks this worked, except when I typed the "sudo conda install rpy2" it refused to find the rpy2 module. Then I did "sudo easy_install rpy2" in the folder you suggested and it worked (with a load of warnings).

Comment: Glad that works! Should have been just `conda install XXX`. Because the `anaconda` folder is in your `home` folder and you have both `Read` and `Write` permission to it. I will update the answer with the related bash command.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that pip installed to the site-packages to python 2.6 since you installed pip with python 2.6 it will default to use that library.

```
 rpy2 in /Library/Python/**2.6**/site-packages/rpy2-2.3.8-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg
```

You can redirect pip installation location or use easy_install2.7 which should be around in /usr/local/bin/